# How does HttpContext.User get it's value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a codebase where the value of `HttpContext.User` is often evaluated yet. I can't see a single point to which it's Assigned a value. I assume it happens deep inside the API.

How does .NET get this value?

Comment: It depends on Authentication mechanism you used. How do you authenticate user?

Comment: It uses HttpAuth but the web.config says    <authentication mode="None" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is creating a `IPrincipal` which is then assigned to `HttpContext.Current.User` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, e.g:

```
public class MyPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    public IIdentity Identity => new MyIdentity();

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class MyIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public string Name => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string AuthenticationType => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public bool IsAuthenticated => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And then

```
var principal = new MyPrincipal();
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
```

Where exactly this is happening depends on your Authentication mechanism.

If your question is because you want to ship your own, do it only If you are experienced with this kind of topic. Security is not trivial.

Instead of creating your own, in most situations it might be better to extend Identity (`IUserStore` etc.):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity